# Typo on Wikipedia's entry on Hoeffding's inequality?

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

In [Wikipedia's entry on Hoeffding's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality#General_case), they state that if $\overline{X} := \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, then
$$ P(\overline{X}-E[\overline{X}] \ge t) \le \exp (-2n^2 t^2)$$
if we assume for simplicity that $a_i=0$ and $b_i=1$ for all $i$.

This is my first encounter with Hoeffding's inequality, so I am unfamiliar with all the different manifestations of this theorem, but regardless, all the other sources I have seen have something along the lines of $\exp (-2nt^2)$ instead. Is Wikipedia's entry a typo?

Remark: I believe that the version of the inequality where we consider $Y := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ instead of the average $\overline{X}$ has the bound $\exp(-2t^2)$. But, nowhere else have I seen $\exp(-2n^2 t^2)$ besides the Wikipedia entry.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you copied down the equation isn't quite right. If $a_i=0$ and $b_i=1$ for all $i$, then the bound is:

$$\exp \left( - \frac{2n^2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)^2} \right)=\exp \left( - \frac{2n^2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n 1} \right)=\exp \left( - \frac{2n^2t^2}{n} \right)=\exp \left(-2nt^2\right).$$

The form on the left is from Wikipedia, which is correct; it's the same as equation (2.6) in the source. The form on the right is what you were expecting.

Comment: Oh I see, that was a silly mistake on my part. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is just a matter of how you define the random variables: the sum ($Y := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$) or the average ($\overline{X} := \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i = \frac 1 n Y$), otherwise the two bounds are equivalent:

$$\Pr(Y - \mathrm{E}[Y] \geq t) \leq \exp \left( - \frac{2t^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)^2} \right),\!$$

with $t = t'\,n$ we have:

$$\Pr(Y - \mathrm{E}[Y] \geq t'n) \leq \exp \left( - \frac{2n^2 t'^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)^2} \right),\!$$

Note that $\Pr(Y - \mathrm{E}[Y] \geq t'n)  = \Pr(\frac{1}{n}(Y - \mathrm{E}[Y]) \geq t') = \Pr(\overline{X} - \mathrm{E}[\overline{X}] \geq t')$, so the above inequality is equivalent to 
$$\Pr(\overline{X} - \mathrm{E}[\overline{X}] \geq t') \leq \exp \left( - \frac{2n^2 t'^2}{\sum_{i=1}^n (b_i - a_i)^2} \right).$$

Comment: Thanks for showing how the two random variables are related!